# Game theory question on a 2 player game

Tags: logic, combinatorial-game-theory

Paul and Luke are playing a game with stacks of black, red and green tiles.
At the start of the game, there are n stacks of one black tile on the board, where n is any positive integer.
Paul begins. There are only two allowed moves:

- Place a red or green tile (from a sufficiently large supply) onto an existing stack. After the move, no two pieces of the same color may be in the same stack. A stack can only consist of a maximum of three tiles.
- Remove two stacks from the game, with the top tiles of the two stacks having the same color. The height can be different.

He who can no longer draw has lost.

You decide
a) for six stacks, so $$ n=6 $$
b) for any even number $$ n>=2 $$ of stacks,

whether either player can play in such a way that she can force the win, and if so, provide such a winning strategy.

I thought about this analyzing the game. For $n=2$ we know that there are only two stacks of black, so it means Paul can directly apply the second rule of the game, so removing two stacks from the game. Does it mean, that with enough time, the same would happen also for $n=6$? This is not very clear to me.

Comment: It's the same for $n=6$ stacks: Paul removes two of the six stacks. Now, Luke will not remove two further stacks because he would lose immediately. So, he will instead place, say a green tile, onto one of the remaining stacks. Paul then places also a green tile on another stack. This goes on until all four stacks are full with two of them of the same colour (red or green). Now, it's Luke's turn again and he must take two stacks which leaves Paul with just two stacks of the same colour. Note that this method works for $n\equiv 2\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 4)$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I‘ll try and solve alone the second part of the problem.

Comment: In addition to simply taking the last stacks, you also win if you pass your opponent two full stacks of opposite color, right?

Comment: @eyeballfrog No it does not work that way. You win if and only if the other person is not allowed to do any of the two possible moves.

Comment: @EnktEnktson - what move would the player have if confronted with eyeballfrog's scenario? They cannot add another tile to either stack, as all three colors are already there, and they cannot remove the two stacks as they have different colors on top.

Comment: This is a first player win if the number of stacks is $\equiv 2\text{ or }3\mod 4$, and a second player win if the number of stacks is $\equiv 0\text{ or 1}\mod 4$. In the former case, the first player removes to stacks on their first turn to convert it the second case, with themselves now acting as the second player. I'll let you discover the 2nd player's strategy in the $n\equiv 0 \mod 4$ case. When $n$ is odd, the last stack cannot be removed, and it also does not affect the 2nd player's strategy. Thus its only impact is to allow two more moves, not changing the outcome.